# Component can't bind existing JS to template view

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, angular5, ckeditor5

I want to integrate CKeditor v5 as it has markdown integration functionality that no other lib offers out of the box. When compiling I am running into multiple problems:

1. Using angular 5 component can't bind existing JS to template view.

Component Template:

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

// Required Dependencies for library construction
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editorclassic/src/classiceditor';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
import GFMDataProcessor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-markdown-gfm/src/gfmdataprocessor';

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
  selector: 'ten-ckeditor',
  styleUrls: ['./ckeditor.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './ckeditor.component.html',
})

export class CkeditorComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(ClassicEditor);

  function Markdown( editor ) {
    editor.data.processor = new GFMDataProcessor();
  }

  ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
  plugins: [
    Markdown,
    Essentials,
    Paragraph,
    Bold,
    Italic,
    Heading,
    BlockQuote,
    Link,
    List
    ],
  toolbar: [
    'headings',
    'bold',
    'italic',
    'blockquote',
    'link',
    'numberedList',
    'bulletedList'
    ]
})
.then(editor => {
  console.log('Editor was initialized', editor);
  editor.setData('This is **bold**.');
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error.stack);
});

  }

}
```

Errors:

> webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/shared/components/ckeditor/ckeditor.component.ts:60
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at ElementReplacer.replace (webpack-internal:///../../../../@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/elementreplacer.js:36)
>       at editor.initPlugins.then.then (webpack-internal:///../../../../@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js:140)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:392)
>       at Object.onInvoke (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4824)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:391)
>       at Zone.run (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:142)
>       at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:873)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4815)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Managed to get this fixed by using  @ViewChild('editor') editor: ElementRef; & referencing this.editor.nativeElement

Comment: The error is caused by `document.querySelector('#editor')` returning no element – you need to pass there some existing element.

Comment: Succeeded integrating this selector part. Also I can see JS working from ES2016. However I have style issues now, that don't compile correctly. Any ideas?
 [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfuevf9t1oqsr6w/Screenshot%202017-12-13%2010.14.51.png?dl=0[link]

Comment: I compiled all styles to extracted into a diffrent styles.scss file. This eliminates errors in compiling styles. I am 100% sure it's not style compile error as this process is outside of compilation. I looked into more detail and discovered new error. [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/rafhwm7abvaukan/Screenshot%202017-12-13%2011.34.54.png?dl=0